# TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined - Button sometimes does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm updating a Facebook ChatBot to DialogFlow Version 2. I have a problem with buttons, they don't work the first time, but if the user sends a text message, and then try again, the buttons start working. I'm working whit Heroku and Node.js, these are the results of heroku log

[image]

This is my function sendToDialogFlow

```
async function sendToDialogFlow(sender, textString, params) {


try {
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(
        config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
        sessionIds.get(sender)
    );

    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: textString,
                languageCode: config.DF_LANGUAGE_CODE,
            },
        },
        queryParams: {
            payload: {
                data: params
            }
        }
    };
    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);

    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    handleDialogFlowResponse(sender, result);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(e);
}
}
```

And here it is handleDialogFlowResponse function

```
function handleDialogFlowResponse(sender, response) {
let responseText = response.fulfillmentMessages.fulfillmentText;

let messages = response.fulfillmentMessages;
let action = response.action;
let contexts = response.outputContexts;
let parameters = response.parameters;

var delay = 4000;

  if (isDefined(action)) {

      sendTypingOn(sender);
      setTimeout(function(){
        sendTypingOff(sender);
        handleDialogFlowAction(sender, action, messages, contexts, parameters);
      },delay);

  } else if (isDefined(messages) && (messages.length == 1 && messages[0].type != 0 || messages.length > 1) ) {

      sendTypingOn(sender);
      setTimeout(function(){
        sendTypingOff(sender);
        handleMessages(messages, sender);
      },delay);

  } else if (responseText == '' && !isDefined(action)) {

  } else if (isDefined(responseText)) {

      sendTypingOn(sender);
      setTimeout(function(){
        sendTypingOff(sender);
        sendTextMessage(sender, responseText);
      },delay);
  }
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the `handleDialogFlowResponse` function to your question? `charCodeAt()`, is a function on a string, so this error means some variable is undefined when it’s expected to be a string, but the code shown doesn’t use that function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: Update: handleDialogFlowResponse added

Comment: Which line is causing the error here?

Comment: Having the same issue, I even wrapped the values in a template string before passing them to the function and still have the same issue >.<